# Can I use reg exp name in a different regular expression

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

I have a regular expression with the Reference Name: `${id}`.
I want to create another regular expression and I was wondering if I can use the above reg ex reference name.

Here is the reg exp I am trying to create:

```
<a href=\\"/([^"]+?)/e\?retURL=%2F${id}\\"
```

Currently when I run my script the above regular expression doesn't return a value.

The above regular expression works fine if use the id value as follows:

```
<a href=\\"/([^"]+?)/e\?retURL=%2F801000000092838\\"
```

But instead of using the actual id value (`801000000092838`) I want it to run with the reg exp name `${id}` to pull the value dynamically.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715437/jmeter-regex-in-beanshell-matcher-pattern-is-cutting-national-character
You might want to define your `pattern` as a string, and then run the regex for every value you pass to it, by dynamically change the `pattern` you pass to the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this, I cannot reproduce your problem using latest [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4), I have:

1. Defined a User Variable `id` with the value of `801000000092838` on [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level
2. Response data: `<a href="http://example.com/e?retURL=%2F801000000092838"`
3. Regular Expression: `<a href="(.+?)/e\?retURL=%2F${id}"`
4. I'm able to see `http://example.com` using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

   [image: JMeter use variable in the regular expression]

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. I have defined the regular expression id with the value of 801000000092838 on the Thread Group level in one of the HTTP requests and defined another regular regular expression in the next HTTP request with the name newid as:

    <a href=\\"/([^"]+?)/e\?retURL=%2F${id}\\"    

and Debug Sampler doesn't show the output of the reg exp     ${newid}    

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with the above reg exp.

I tried this using Jmeter 3.2 and 4.0